# Quicker way for date comparing in PHP

Tags: php, date, date-comparison

Currently I'm doing something like the following

```
if(date("H") > 23) {
    if(date("H") < 24) {
        if(date("i") < 10) {
            if(date("i") < 20) {
                //perform an action if it's between 11:10pm and 11:20pm
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What's a quicker and cleaner way of perfoming such `if` statements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a whole lot less code but probably easier to read:

```
$now   = new DateTime();
$early = new DateTime('23:10');
$late  = new DateTime('23:20');
if ($now > $early && $now < $late) {
    //perform an action if it's between 11:10pm and 11:20pm
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to do this. Here is one.

```
$now = date('H:i');
$target1 = date('23:10');
$target2 = date('23:20');
if ($now > $target1 && $now < $target2)
{
     // Do something
}
```